# Are these preferences convex?

Tags: microeconomics

$Let$ the utility function defined to be :

$$U(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$$

I believe they are convex, the set which is preferred to a specific indifference curve is convex, but the answer sheet says that it is concave? What is the reason behind this? Or is the answer sheet just wrong?

Comment: Here we are talking about convexity of the indifference curves

Answer (score 1):

The ***utility function* is concave**, but the ***preference* that the function represents is convex**. It seems you're confusing between the convexity of two different objects.